# Amount of binary strings

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

i `ve got this problem, can you help me ?

I can solve subquestion a) but i really don`t have a clue how to find recursive formula.

S_n is the amount of binary strings with size n, which don’t include substring 010.

1. Find some of S_n for small values of n.
2. Find recursive formula for S_n.

Comment: Have you done 1?  You should do that up to $5$, say, to get some idea.

Answer (score 1):

$S(n) = 2S(n-1) - S(n-2) + S(n-3)$

(Start on a large whiteboard)
Draw a binary tree with the possible cases. Left for 0 right for 1. Three or Four levels are enough to get an idea.

The right subtree is  $S(n-1)$
 
The left subtree is  $S(n-1)-S(n-2)+S(n-3)$

BTW some values for S(n) are:
$S(3) = 7$
$S(4) = 12$
$S(5) = 21$
$S(6) = 37$
$S(7) = 65$
$S(8) = 114$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** One way is to look at $3$ sequences:

- $a_n$: number of valid sequences of length $n$
- $b_n$: number of valid sequences of length $n$ ending with $0$
- $c_n$: number of valid sequences of length $n$ ending with $01$

This should help you write a recurrence relation for $a_n$...

Comment: It might also be worth having $d_n$: number of valid sequences of length $n$ ending with $11$, so for $n\ge 2$ you have $a_n=b_n+c_n+d_n$

Answer (score 0):

Using notation above

Any sequence $a_{n+1}$ can be obtained by appending $0$ or $1$ to any valid sequence of size $n$ ending in $11$ there are $(a_{n}-b_{n}-c_{n})$ such sequences. Similarly we can append $0$ or $1$ to any sequence ending in $0$ but we can only append $1$ to any sequence ending in $01$.

Hence $$a_{n+1}=2(a_{n}-c_{n}-b_{n})+2b_{n}+c_{n}=2a_{n}-c_{n}.$$

Now consider $c_{n}$ we can obtain $c_{n}$ be appending $01$ onto the end of any valid sequence in $a_{n-2}$ provided it does not end in $01$, there are $a_{n-2}-c_{n-2}$ such sequences. Hence $c_{n}=a_{n-2}-c_{n-2}$ and so $c_{n}=a_{n-2}-a_{n-4}+a_{n-6}-a_{n-8}...$